# Как подгрузить вложенные комментарии при клике на корневой?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть 4 компонента: Comments, Comment, CommentForm, api. В Comments рендерятся компоненты Comment в виде дерева. В итоге мы получаем список комментариев в виде дерева. Не могу придумать как сделать так, чтобы Comment Выезжали только пo клику на Comments.

````
  //Comment.js
   ```import CommentForm from "./CommentForm";

    const Comment=({comment, replies, currentUserId, deleteComment, activeComment, updateComment, setActiveComment, addComment, parentId=null})=>{
        const fiveMinutes=300000;
        const timePassed=new Date()-new Date(comment.createdAt)>fiveMinutes;
        const canReply=Boolean(currentUserId);
        const canEdit=currentUserId===comment.userId && !timePassed;
        const canDelete=currentUserId===comment.userId && !timePassed;
        const createdAt=new Date(comment.createdAt).toLocaleDateString();
     const isReplying=activeComment&&activeComment.type==="replying"&&activeComment.id===comment.id;
const isEditing=activeComment&&activeComment.type==="editing"&&activeComment.id===comment.id;
        const replyId=parentId?parentId:comment.id;
        return( 
        <div className="comment">
           <div className="comment-image-container">
            <img src="../img/ava.png" width={50} height={50} alt="ava" />
           </div>
           <div className="comment-right-part">
            <div className="comment-content">
             <div className="comment-autor">{comment.username}</div>
             <div className="comment-data">{createdAt}</div>
            </div>
            {!isEditing&&<div className="comment-text">{comment.body}</div>}
              {isEditing && <CommentForm submitLabel="Update" hasCancelButton initialText={comment.body} handleSubmit={(text)=>updateComment(text, comment.id)} handleCancel={()=>setActiveComment(null)}/>}
             <div className="comment-actions">
                {canReply&&<div className="comment-action" onClick={()=>setActiveComment({id:comment.id, type:"replying"})}>Reply</div>}
               {canEdit&&<div className="comment-action" onClick={()=>setActiveComment({id:comment.id, type:"editing"})}>Edit</div>}
               {canDelete&&<div className="comment-action" onClick={()=>deleteComment(comment.id)}>Delete</div>}
            </div>
            {isReplying&&(<CommentForm submitLabel="Reply" handleSubmit={(text)=>addComment(text, replyId)}/>)}
            {replies.length>0 && (
                <div className="replies">
                   {replies.map(reply=>(
                        <Comment 
                        comment={reply} 
                        key={reply.id} 
                        replies={[]} 
                        currentUserId={currentUserId}
                        deleteComment={deleteComment}
                        activeComment={activeComment}
                        setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
                        parentId={comment.id}
                        updateComment={updateComment}
                        addComment={addComment}/>
                        
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
           </div>
        </div>
        )
    };
    export default Comment;```


    //CommentForm.js
   ```import React from "react";

const CommentForm=({submitLabel, handleSubmit, hasCancelButton=false, initialText='', handleCancel})=>{
        const [text, setText]=React.useState(initialText);
        const isTextAreaDisabled=text.length===0;
        const onSubmit=event=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            handleSubmit(text);
            setText("");
        }
        return (
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <textarea className="comment-form-textarea" value={text} onChange={(e)=>setText(e.target.value)}></textarea>
            <button className="comment-form-button" disabled={isTextAreaDisabled}>{submitLabel}</button>
{hasCancelButton&&( <button 
type="button" className="comment-form-button comment-form-cancel-button"
                onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
            )}
            </form>
        )
    };
    export default CommentForm;```



   //Comments.js
    ```import React from "react";
    import { getComments as getCommentsApi } from "./api";
    import { createComment as createCommentApi } from "./api";
    import { deleteComment as deleteCommentApi } from "./api";
    import { updateComment as updateCommentApi } from "./api";
    import Comment from "./Comment";
    import CommentForm from "./CommentForm";

    const Comments=({currentUserId})=>{
    const [backendComments, setBackendComments]=React.useState([]);
    const [activeComment, setActiveComment]=React.useState(null);
    const rootComments=backendComments.filter(backendComment=>backendComment.parentId===null);
    const getReplies=(commendId)=>{
        return backendComments.filter(backendComment=>backendComment.parentId===commendId)
        .sort((a,b)=>new Date(a.createdAt).getTime()-new Date(b.createdAt).getTime());
    };
    const addComment=(text, parentId)=> {
        console.log("addComment", text, parentId);
        createCommentApi(text, parentId).then(comment=>{
            setBackendComments([comment, ...backendComments]);
            setActiveComment(null);
        })
    };
    const updateComment=(text, commendId)=>{
        updateCommentApi(text, commendId).then(()=>{
            const updatedBackendComments=backendComments.map(backendComment=>{
                if (backendComment.id===commendId) {
                    return {...backendComment, body:text}
                }
                return backendComment;
            });
            setBackendComments(updatedBackendComments);
            setActiveComment(null);
        })
    }
    const deleteComment=(commentId)=>{
    if(window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        deleteCommentApi(commentId).then(()=>{
           const updatedBackendComments=backendComments.filter(backendComment=>backendComment.id!==commentId);
           setBackendComments(updatedBackendComments);
        });
    }
    }
    console.log(backendComments)
    React.useEffect(()=>{
    getCommentsApi().then((data)=> setBackendComments(data));
    }, []);
        return (
            <div className="comments">
                <h3 className="comments-title">Comments</h3>
                <div className="comment-form-title">Write comment</div>
                <CommentForm submitLabel="Write" handleSubmit={addComment}/>
                <div className="comments-container">
                {rootComments.map((rootComment)=>(
                    <Comment
                    key={rootComment.id}
                    comment={rootComment} 
                    replies={getReplies(rootComment.id)} 
                    currentUserId={currentUserId}
                    deleteComment={deleteComment}
                    activeComment={activeComment}
                    updateComment={updateComment}
                    setActiveComment={setActiveComment}
                    addComment={addComment}/>
                ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    export default Comments;```

```///api.js
export const getComments = async () => {
    let today =new Date();
let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    return [
      {
        id: "1",
        body: "First comment",
        username: "Jack",
        userId: "1",
        parentId: null,
        createdAt: today,
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        body: "Second comment",
        username: "John",
        userId: "2",
        parentId: null,
        createdAt: today,
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        body: "First comment first child",
        username: "John",
        userId: "2",
        parentId: "1",
        createdAt: today,
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        body: "Second comment second child",
        username: "John",
        userId: "2",
        parentId: "2",
        createdAt: today,
      },
    ];
  };
  export const createComment = async (text, parentId = null) => {
    return {
      id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
      body: text,
      parentId,
      userId: "1",
      username: "John",
      createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    };
  };
  export const deleteComment = async () => {
    return {};
  };
  export const updateComment = async (text) => {
    return { text };
  };```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо определить элемент, который будет отвечать за показ и скрытие компонентов.
Допустим это будет вот этот элемент и компонента Comment

```
<div className="comment-text">{comment.body}</div>
```

Далее создаем state в компоненте Comment, который будет отвечать за отображение вложенных комментариев именно к данному сообщению

```
const [showReply, setShowReply] = useState(false);
```

Модифицируем наш элемент и добавляем событие клика. По событию значение переменной будет меняться с true на false и наоборот

```
<div className="comment-text" onClick={() => setShowReply(s => !s)}>{comment.body}</div>
```

Ну и в том месте, где идет отображение вложенных комментариев, добавляем проверку на значение переменной showReply

```
{replies.length>0 && (
```

Меняем вот так

```
{showReply && replies.length>0 && (
```

Итого, каждое сообщение будет управлять состоянием отображения своих вложенных комментариев, причем на всей вложенности.

Если надо изначально все комментарии скрыть, то проделайте аналогичную операцию в компоненте Comments.

Comment: Спасибо огроменное!!!!!!!