# Скрытие вложенных списков

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Возникла такая проблема. Есть функция, которая отрисовывает массив объектов. Она рекурсивная. Задача такая: необходимо реализовать скрытие дочерних элементов списка при клике на кнопку свернуть (-) и соответственно развернуть, если нажата кнопка (+). Подскажите как это можно реализовать, пока ничего путного не получается:
[image: Примерная структура должна быть такая]
Функция отрисовки:

```
function listRender(tasks, style) {

return (
  <ul className={style}>
    {
      tasks.map((task) => {     
            
        if (!task.isTaskGroup) {
          return <li key={task.id}>
            {
              task.tasksTreeItems.length > 0 && 
              <>
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
              </> 
            }
            <div className='div'>
              <span>
                {task.performer.displayName}, {task.performer.position} <em>{task.state}</em>
              </span>
              <div>
                {task.content && <span>Задание: {task.content}</span>}
              </div>
              <div>
                {task.createDate && <span>Исполнение с {dateFormat(new Date(task.createDate))}</span>}
              </div>
                {task.endDate && <span>Выполнить до {dateFormat(new Date(task.endDate))}</span>}
              <div>
                {task.report && <span>Отчет: {task.report}</span>}
              </div>
            </div>
            {task.tasksTreeItems.length > 0 && listRender(task.tasksTreeItems, style)}
          </li>
        } else {
          return <li key={task.id}>
            {
              task.tasksTreeItems.length > 0 && 
              <>
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
              </>
            }
            <div className='div'>
              <span>{task.author.displayName}, {task.author.position} <em>{task.state}</em></span>
              <div>
                {task.content && <span>Резолюция: {task.content}</span>}
              </div>
              <div>
              {task.endDate && <span>Выполнить до {dateFormat(new Date(task.endDate))}</span>}
              </div>
            </div>
            {task.tasksTreeItems.length > 0 ? listRender(task.tasksTreeItems, style) : 'child'}
          </li>
        }
      })
    }
  </ul>
)
```

}

Отрисовывается в App:

```
return <div className="App">
  <ul>
    {
      listRender(tasksTree, 'main')
    }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Пробовал добавлять состояние, которое изменяется при клике на кнопку, но тогда оно распространяется и на другие элементы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат [Как догрузить вложенные комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460819/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9)